# How to make a multiple recipient textbox like iMessage?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, addressbook

I am trying to replicate the functionality of choosing recipients in iMessage. Where you can either type the phone number or email address in the textbox or choose from the addressbook.

I am using the [SwiftAddressBook Wrapper](https://github.com/SocialbitGmbH/SwiftAddressBook) for addressbook access. Made a textbox, where user can type or tap a button to open address book UI and choose an email or phone number which is presented in the textbox as text.

My question is how to present the selected or typed phone/email as an entry instead of just text in the text box just like iMessage does. In iMessage. when you tap on an entry it is selected as a whole and you can delete it with backspace. Also additional entries are added with coma separation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the term for this is "TokenField". If you search for that you can find some libraries. Here is one that looks promising: https://github.com/thermogl/TITokenField

Comment: Also this one looks pretty decent and for a slightly different use case (it acts more like Mail than Messages) https://github.com/venmo/VENTokenField